# Container width is 1170px, but I expected 970px when the port view width is 1280px

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this simple code:

```
<div class="container">foobar</div>
```

Check the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8593/). **Note:** I have not used a SO snippet since the window "Result" is not resizeable.

The problem: I expected a 970px width `container`, when the width of the window "Result" is 1280px, like here: [getbootstrap.com](http://www.getbootstrap.com) ( "Preprocessors", "One framework, every device".. area), but I get a 1170px width `container`. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Any screen width greater than 1200px will have a 1170px container by default. If you want the container to be 970px you would have to override Bootstrap's default behavior.

Comment: thanks, so the bootstrap used at getbootstrap.com is not the default one?

Comment: It is, if you inspect the code on getboostrap.com in a window greater than 1200px you will see that the container is 1170px there as well.

Comment: that's not true, it is 970px, I have just checked it for a 1280px width screen.